Why is the NodeJS version on Kudu different from my App version?
I am getting the error below while deploying my NodeJS app on Azure:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader 
Error: Cannot find module '...'

According to some research, it should be a node version issue.
My App is supposed to run with the stack Node-18-lts, and I set the engines accordingly in my packages.json file, but when I bash into Kudu, I see node 14.
Why isn't it Node 18 ? I don't know if that will fix my issue, but at least, it seems to be an issue too.
UPDATES
Log Stream extract:
  | npm info using npm@9.6.4
  | npm info using node@v18.19.1
  | > my-api@0.1.0 start
  | > strapi start
  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137
  |   throw err;
  |   ^
  | Error: Cannot find module '../dist/cli'
  | Require stack:
  | - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/strapi
  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
  |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/strapi:2:1)
  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12) {
  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  |   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/strapi' ]
  | }

Kudu Console output:
    __ __          __      __    _ __     
   / //_/_  _ ____/ /_  __/ /   (_) /____ 
  / ,< / / / / __  / / / / /   / / __/ _  
 / /| / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /___/ / /_/  __/
/_/ |_\__,_/\__,_/\__,_/_____/_/\__/\___/ 

                                          
DEBUG CONSOLE | AZURE APP SERVICE ON LINUX

Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
Kudu Version : 20240315.1
Commit       : xxx

kudu_ssh_user@xxx:/$ node -v
v14.19.2


Are you deploying your app via GitHub, Visual Studio extension, or Azure Devops?

What does your log stream show?

@SirraSneha, I added some updates to my question

I deploy with GitHub Actions

can you share your GitHub repo if possible ?

try to check the node version via SSH console it gave correct node 18.19.1
refer this its my node web app ,and when i'm using bash section I'm getting same node version as 14.19.2  image

It seems like SSH works only when the app is running. My app failed to start, so I have no running container

The error you're encountering is not related to node versions.
In the Bash section of Azure Web App, the default NodeJS version is v14.19.2

When I checked the NodeJs version via SSH console it correctly gave Node 18.19.1 version.

According to the error message you've provided, I added the line below to your package.json file, as described in this Document
"scripts":  {  
"start":  "node node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js start"  
}

Below is the complete package.json file:
Package.json:
{
"name": "osanwebsite-api",
"private": true,
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "A Strapi application",
"scripts": {
"develop": "strapi develop",
"start": "node node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js start",
"build": "strapi build",
"strapi": "strapi"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"dependencies": {
"@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.23.1",
"@strapi/plugin-graphql": "4.23.1",
"@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.23.1",
"@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.23.1",
"@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.24.0",
"@strapi/strapi": "4.23.1",
"better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
"styled-components": "5.3.3"
},
"author": {
"name": "A Strapi developer"
},
"strapi": {
"uuid": "53252aee-466b-4b03-92c9-72ece5437d0c"
},
"engines": {
"node": "18.16.1",
"npm": "9.5.1
},
"license": "MIT"
}

After deploying the app to Azure App Service, I added the following startup command in app configurations.
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa


Here's the output after deployment:


Thank you so much, the problem was the start script in packages.json.  I also had to change the Start command in Azure config to pm2 start npm --no-daemon -- start, I was receiving this error: Error while serving /home/site/wwwroot/build/register-admin with content-type text/plain : ENOENT: no such file or directory when submitting the form. Thanks again.
